# using a join inside a trigger, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a database that needs to update a field in one table when another table is updated. However, the table that is being updated doesn't contain the values I need... it just contains an ID to a third table that has that value. Basically, I'm looking for something that does this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_TableA AFTER UPDATE TableA
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE TableB SET points=TableC.points 
WHERE TableC.cID=NEW.cID;
END
```

cID, of course, being present in both TableA and TableC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE
  TableB b
  JOIN TableC с
    ON c.cID = b.cID
SET
  b.points = c.points
WHERE c.cID=NEW.cID;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understated the complexity of my problem and found another solution using if statements and variables and other things. I wanted to come back and let you know if it worked, but I decided to go another route. Thanks anyway.