# Getting information from a third table in a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

What I want to do is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067954/using-a-join-inside-a-trigger-mysql), except the action is an insert not an update. I will use the same example used in that question, modified for my context;

I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_TableA AFTER UPDATE TableA
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO TableB (cID, points) VALUES (NEW.cID, TableC.points);
END
```

cID is present in TableA and TableC. Because it's not an UPDATE I can't do a JOIN like in the other question (right?). Is there any way to get the data from TableC INSERTED into TableB here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be the trigger that you need:

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_TableA AFTER UPDATE TableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TableB (cID, points)
  SELECT TableC.cID, TableC.points
  FROM   TableC
  WHERE  TableC.cID = NEW.cID;
END
```

You don't need a JOIN in this case, but you could use the syntax [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)